# Bootstrap navbar not working laravel blade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi i have layouts folder where my nav file is located

```
<h3 class="text-muted">Company Name or Logo</h3>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light rounded mb-3">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-md-center nav-justified w-100">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/dataform/public">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/dataform/public/register">Register RA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">

    @if(Auth::check())
                <a class="nav-link" href="/dataform/public/logout">Logout</a>
        @else
            <a class="nav-link" href="/dataform/public/login">Login</a>
@endif

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and im calling this on my master layout

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="masthead">


        @include('layouts.nav')

    </div>


<div class="contaainer">

    @yield('content')


</div>
```

On small devices the toggle button is not working not opening at all , what should i fix here , TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `@include()` a complete path, Starting after `/views`

For example you have directory structure like :

```
project/resources/views/admin/layouts/nav.blade.php
```

Then your include will be :

`@include('admin.layouts.nav')`

**Note** : Check your spelling, It should be`.blade.php`.

Comment: My include is working properly , there is a bug in navbar bootstrap code which i cant find